# laravel response() function is not setting iframe origin properly

Tags: javascript, laravel, iframe, xss, same-origin-policy

i have a laravel 5.7 app. i have an iframe in one page with

```
<iframe src="{{ url('pdf') }}" width="100%" height="80%" id="frame_id" name="test_frame"></iframe>
```

when

```
Route::get('/pdf', function () {  
    return 'abc';
});
```

then inside console i write

```
window.frames["frame_id"].contentWindow.origin => http://cms.test
```

but when

```
Route::get('/pdf', function () {
    return response()->file('test.pdf');
});
```

then

```
window.frames["frame_id"].contentWindow.origin
```

=> `SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "origin" on cross-origin object`

why the origin is changing in both cases? how do I fix this since due to cross origin I am unable to manipulate iframe dom

Answer (score 0):

The explanation above doesn't make it apparent as to what you're trying to do, but have a look at [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf) page for how to properly configure Cross-Site Request Forgery settings.

It's important to understand what CSRF is.  It's essentially a security feature that keeps me from copying your HTML, modifying it to do something you didn't intend, and then sending a request with something that could exploit your site.

In order to make your logic work, you need to bypass Laravel's built-in CSRF middleware.  For production servers, I would NOT remove it, but for testing, you can just comment out the line containing "\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class" in your Kernel.php file and that should do the trick.

Comment: i disabled it as well. no effect